# map url not showing on browserfield

Tags: blackberry

I've display a webpage using browserfield. It showing all webpage successfully.

But when i pass the this url ,http://maps.doapps.com/traffic/traffic.php?lat=44.972000&lng=-93.283997.

The map didnot show. only the String show as "Map div".  In browser the map is show. but not in browserfield.

My code is,

```
BrowserFieldConfig config = new BrowserFieldConfig();
     String userAgent = "BlackBerry" + DeviceInfo.getDeviceName() + "/" +    DeviceInfo.getSoftwareVersion() +" Profile/" + System.getProperty("microedition.profiles") +" Configuration/" + System.getProperty( "microedition.configuration") + " VendorID/" + Branding.getVendorId();
     config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.JAVASCRIPT_ENABLED, Boolean.TRUE);    
     config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.USER_AGENT, userAgent);

BrowserField myBrowserField = new BrowserField(config);

myBrowserField.requestContent("http://maps.doapps.com/traffic/traffic.php?lat=44.972000&lng=-93.283997");
```

How to show the url in bb browserfield, any setting need to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BlackBerry Browser Field not support fully JQuery . so may be the problem caused by BrowerField jQuery support .

you can use static maps to display what you need . or invoking  Maps installed on your device .